# is there any ways to print the exact value of a double that exceeds Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY in java?

Tags: java

i want to print the 1477th fibonacci number in java but i am getting "Infinity" or NumberFormatException when using BigDecimal, please help

1477th fibonacci number:
211475298697902185255785861961179135570552502746803252174956226558634024323947666637137823932524397611864671566211908330263377425204552074188208686993669123754004340250943108709212299180422293009765404930508242975773774612140021599477983006713536106549441161323499077298115887067363710153036315849480388057657

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work with `BigDecimal`

See the following code

```
BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(
                "211475298697902185255785861961179135570552502746803252174956226558634024323947666637137823932524397611864671566211908330263377425204552074188208686993669123754004340250943108709212299180422293009765404930508242975773774612140021599477983006713536106549441161323499077298115887067363710153036315849480388057657");
        System.out.println(decimal);
```

Use BigDecimal constructor with **String** as input